# Group by and left join in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables as shown below:

```
Table 1

col1|col2|col3
A1  | 3  |  B1
A1  | 4  |  C1
A2  | 2  |  B1

Table 2

col1|col2|col3
A1  | 4  |  2
A1  | 5  |  3
A1  | 11 |  5
A2  | 0  |  10
```

I want to do a left join on `Table 1` and aggregate `col3` from `Table 2` as long as `col2` in `Table 2` is greater than `col2` from `Table 1` and less than equal to `col2`+7 from `Table 1`.

The result would be as shown below

```
col1|col2|col3 |col4
A1  | 3  |  B1 | 5
A1  | 4  |  C1 | 8
A2  | 2  |  B1 | null
```

**I have the following query but I get only about 50% of the records in Table 1 and don't see the nulls if applicable. There seems to be a problem with the where clause but I m not sure what is wrong.**

```
#standardSQL
select A.col1, A.col2, A.col3, sum(B.col3) as col4
from `Table 1` as A
left join `Table 2` as B
on A.col1 = B.col1
where B.col2 > A.col2 and B.col2 <= A.col2+7
group by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the where statement in the join clause like this:

```
#standardSQL
select A.col1, A.col2, A.col3, sum(B.col3) as col4
from `Table 1` as A
left join `Table 2` as B
on A.col1 = B.col1
and B.col2 > A.col2 
and B.col2 <= A.col2+7
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!